# How to trim the text in different columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a string from database field which contains the data in below format. The `UW:`,`Loading:`, `CBE:` fields can be present.

ex1:

```
"[UW:Loading25,CBE]
[Loading: 100;120;130]
[CBE:150;170;190]"
```

ex2:

```
"[UW: CBE]
[CBE: 100;122;130]"
```

ex3:

```
"[UW:Loading25]
[Loading: 100;120;130]"
```

I have to separate them in different columns as mentioned below:

```
     UW       |    Loading     |  CBE  
--------------|----------------|------------
Loading25,CBE |  100;120;130   | 150;170;190
--------------|----------------|------------
CBE           |                |100;122;130 
--------------|----------------|------------
Loading25     |  100;120;130   |
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` together with `ltrim` for each search patterns :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select '[UW:Loading25,CBE][Loading: 100;120;130][CBE:150;170;190]' from dual union all
 select '[UW: CBE][CBE: 100;122;130]' from dual union all
 select '[UW:Loading25][Loading: 100;120;130]' from dual  
)
select ltrim(regexp_substr(str,'UW:([^]]+)'),'UW:') as uw,
       ltrim(regexp_substr(str,'Loading:([^]]+)'),'Loading:') as loading,
       ltrim(regexp_substr(str,'CBE:([^]]+)'),'CBE:') as cbe
  from t;

UW               LOADING        CBE
-------------    -------------  ------------
Loading25,CBE    100;120;130    150;170;190
CBE                             100;122;130
Loading25        100;120;130
```

*Repeating words such as `Loading` or `CBE` should be noticed during the match of patterns.*

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, the above solution is not working for some scenarios like :[UW: CBE]
[CBE: 100;122;130]. Please can you tell whats wrong

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh, you're right. I converted to the above one which works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks. that worked. Can you please tell me some link to go through the Regexp so that i can determine myself. I need to few other functionalities as well.

Comment: you're welcome @Ashutosh. [Oracle Tutorial Link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/) is a nice source, where you can search from right upper part for those string operations such as `regexp_like`, `regexp_substr`,`regexp_count`..etc.